# Is it possible to build powerful server applications online using Java applets?

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to create an account based website (one where you can sign up for an account, log in to your account, etc.) and I am wondering if it is possible to build a website like this solely using a single Java applet.

Comment: Even if it were possible, it would not be a good idea.  If the entire app. can be encompassed by a Java app., shed the browser completely and launch the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 2):

An applet is not a website (and by extension a web application).

Even if you consider it to be, you still can't do it with just one applet -- you still need to build the server side code where all the data gets saved, which I am assuming is what you want.  In this case, the applet is the visible part of the app that the user sees, in their browser or applet viewer, while the server application is the code that saves all the user data, verifies the user, etc....

You might be better off just building a website using javascript/html/css for the client and your server platform of choice.

Comment: Okay, yes, I can do this. I'm just wondering if building a website like this is a good idea with Java applets, if not, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: *"you still can't do it with just one applet"* That statement does not quite make sense to me, however *"you still can't do it with just (one or many) applets"* would make perfect sense.  Is that what you meant? If so, could you edit your answer?  I'd offer to up-vote if you do, but I already did that.  ;)  Why not edit so I can delete this comment?

Answer (score 2):

Well it is possible but I would consider to pick less exotic way to do this(servlets/jsf). Also you must know that applet can be only at client-side.

Answer (score 0):

An applet is a client, not a server. Your question is ill-formed.